# iOS app and LGPL issue

Tags: lgpl

I have an iOS app which use the ffmpeg library, and iOS should compile in static link. According to the LGPLv2, do I release my source code related my UI or other bussiness logic ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing and legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The interaction between the LGPL and Apple's app store is a disputed issue. The only way to get advice you can rely on is to ask a lawyer. I believe that you have two choices -- you can either open source your entire application or you can make available all the object code (`.o` and `.a` files) needed to re-link your application.

Comment: thanks. I got some information from other people. I can open my modified ffmpeg with the object-files (my business logic). However, other said, "Apple imposes additional restrictions on top of PL/LGPL
like only to install on 5 machines that was found a problem for e.g. VLC"

Comment: I found another link about iPhone and LGPL: http://multinc.com/2009/08/24/compatibility-between-the-iphone-app-store-and-the-lgpl/ . Your information is very useful. I will ask a lawyer as well.

Comment: It doesn't matter what Apple does. As the LGPL says, "You are not responsible for enforcing compliance by third parties with this License. "